# Create emails alerts when an update failed using the API from an external system

Tags: api, soap-api, force.com

We have an external ERP system which is where we have all our Customer data. Every change that we made in the ERP goes straight to Salesforce using the API. So, we don't allow to edit the accounts in Salesforce to any user (only to the admin), it has to be done only through the external ERP.

My concern is that in 95% of the cases everything works smooth. However sometimes the accounts are not being updated for some specific errors (like parents accounts, inactive owners...). How can I receive an email alert when an update has been not successful using the API? What is the best approach in terms of the feature that Salesforce offers?

Currently, if there is an error I have to go to the logs and see what happened which can consume a lot of time.

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: The only way to notify someone of an error an external service had during an API update is to have the notification be triggered by and come from the external system. Now if you know what happened and it is the results of a trigger or code then you can catch that in SF code and send of a notification but that would happen for ALL use cases unless you have an API user and limit the notification to that user. AFAIK

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I don't the reason of the error...I have to go the logs and see what was the response that Salesforce sent to the API in order to see the type of error....The user that I'm using is the admin so I don't think is a good idea. Is there anyway to check only the answer from the API to the external system?